# VI Editor : Yank the entire file to clipboard (specific to OS X)

Tags: macos, vim

Is there any way to copy all lines from a file to clipboard in VI editor. I have tried `*yG`, `+yG`, `"+yG` and `:%y+` from previous posts in SO, but nothing works in OS X.

Comment: are you using macvim or vim inside a terminal?

Comment: I am using vim inside terminal

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The default Vim shipped with Mac OS X, `/usr/bin/vi[m]`, isn't compiled with clipboard support.

You have three options:

1. **use `pbcopy` from the command line, without using Vim**

   ```
    $ cat filename | pbcopy
   ```
2. **use `pbcopy` from Vim**

   ```
    :%w !pbcopy
   ```
3. **get your own Vim with clipboard support**

   You can do that through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), by downloading [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) or by building [from the source](https://www.vim.org/download.php#unix).

Also the correct way to use a specific register with `y` is `"{register}y`.

See `$ man pbcopy` in your terminal and `:help clipboard` and `:help !` in Vim.

Comment: Great! pbcopy is awesome. :)

Answer (score 4):

`G` just means "go to the end of the file", and you need quotes before `*` or `+` to make them effective as clipboard registers. You're looking for something more like `gg"*yG` which means:

`gg` - go to the top of the file

`"*` - use the `*` register

`y` - begin yank

`G` - go to the bottom of the file

or you could use `:!cat % | pbcopy` which is not unlike the fine solutions romainl provided.

Answer (score 1):

vim --version | grep clipboard, if you see "-clipboard",  you won't do that . Your vim doesn't support it. You need recompile the source code。

## Compile

```
$./configure \ --enable-gui=auto --with-features=huge --with-x
$ make && sudo make install
```